# Solenoid magnetic induction graph

Tags: current, electromagnetism, solenoid, homework, graph

I need help solving this problem, if anyone had a similar problem it would help me a lot.

A table is given with the current flowing through the solenoid,also values ​​for the magnetic induction vector at the middle and end of the solenoid are given:

[image]

How to draw an appropriate graph based on this table?

I know that the magnetic induction at the middle of the solenoid is always greater than at the end of the solenoid,also increasing the current increases the magnetic induction.

I don't understand how to draw a graph based on this table?

Thanks in advance!

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

Do you understand the concept of a graph?

This answer isn't 'solving your homework problem', it's 'showing you what a graph is'.

Put current on the x axis, going across, that's where we conventionally put the thing we are controlling, the independent variable, or the abscissa.

Put magnetic field on the y axis, going up, which is where we conventionally plot the response, the dependent variable(s), or the ordinate(s).

Use pencil and graph paper, or enter these figures into a spreadsheet, select the data, and ask it to make a graph of them.

[image]

Note that I've committed the cardinal sin of not labeling my axes. That would get you points docked in an exam answer! LibreOffice and most other spreadsheet programs have the tools to do that, and with a pencil and graph paper, it's just a matter of writing 'solenoid current (mA)' at the end of the x axis, and 'B field (mT)' on the y axis.

That's all there is to it. That's an appropriate graph based on that table.

Maybe you're concerned about the next stage, how to interpret the graph? Why aren't the traces linear with current? Why aren't the traces proportional to each other? Do I believe the right thing has been measured? Is it noisy? That's the next stage of an investigation.

Amused post-script: Had I not looked it up to check, I would have got [ordinate and abscissa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abscissa_and_ordinate) the wrong way round!